# Shopify adding offers to items when checkout to change the total order price

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am looking to be able to add offers to my items in Shopify. E.G if a customer orders 3 items then the total order price would get set to something like $15 but if the customer orders like 5 items the total order price would be set to something like $20.

It would also need to work if 4 items were added to the checkout so the price would come out something like 3 items for $15 + $5.95 for the 4th item and so on for the other items.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can make order amounts as variants and set their price accordingly. you cannot change anything like that in the checkout

Answer (score 0):

Each variant in your Shopify store has a fixed price.  At this time, you are unable to change what you charge for that variant item on an order-by-order basis.

The popular way around this, is to create multiple variants of the same product, with different prices for different quantities.

Example:
product: widget
variant: widget-3-or-less  price: $10
variant: widget-4-to-10    price: $8
variant: widget-10-or-more price: $5

Clearly you don't want people to be able to add whichever variant they want, or else everyone would simply add the cheapest one without any regard to the required quantity.  So you need some sort of backend application that will safeguard the variant selection, and automatically determine which variant should be in a customer's cart based on their desired quantity, and adjust their cart accordingly.

It's a lot of work to code from scratch.  Completely possible, but, in most situations it is more viable to use a 3rd party Shopify App to handle it.  In your case, the "Quantity Breaks" app by Bold Apps would work great.  It has all of that functionality already made and ready to go.
https://apps.shopify.com/quantity-breaks